# Ableton Live 8 MIDI tracks recorded without a tempo reference. Need export to Sibelius notation software

Tags: midi, ableton-live, scoring

Having successfully extracted a midi performance from a pc circa 1986, into Ableton Live8, I now have copied each track into its own MIDI file and imported these files into the notation software I'm using (Sibelius).

The problem comes in where the measures Sibelius created (probably from the tempo data in Live8's midi file) do not line up with the intended measure breaks - of course.

What's the best way to produce a correctly metered score here? Again, the working pieces are:

- Original source Midi file, run from the Midi out of a 1986 computer.
- Ableton Live8 to record midi
  Sibelius, to notate.

Comment: besides the tempo, are the time signatures correct in Ableton?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what it it's doing to your measures?

Comment: I guess you need to quantize everything, most of it manually.